# Proper way to save/update a one-off timestamp in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to Rails, and looking for the 'right' way to do something that seems straight-forward, but nothing I've read about sounds quite right.

I have a Rails app on Heroku, and I've added a call to an endpoint that depends on an external system. If that call is unsuccessful there'll be some follow up needed, so I save details to the error log. I've added a notification email (to a slack room for this sort of thing) to prompt me to check the logs and follow up if it happens.

In case the endpoint gets bogged down and fails repeatedly, I want to be able to throttle the slack alert so I don't spam everyone (for example, only email the slack room if 30 min have gone by since the last time it alerted).

To do this, I imagine I need:

- somewhere to save a timestamp for the last email notification for the error
- whenever the error occurs, compare with that timestamp and only email slack room if the 30-min window has passed. Then update the timestamp with the new value.

What's an appropriate place to save this kind of timestamp value? I've read that global variables are the devil (and wouldn't actually work in this case), but the other options (adding database field, trying the simpleconfig gem) seem excessive/incorrect for something internal that I don't even know will happen once, let alone frequently.

Is there a lightweight way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

A popular choice would be to store it in a Redis store -- especially if you already have one set up for something else, like caching. As this is itself ephemeral data, you could even use the `Rails.cache` API to abstract away the detail and have this code just trust that it gets stored *somewhere*.

Failing that, the most straightforward solution is probably to create a tiny single-row table and store it in there: it's overkill, but doesn't involve doing anything unusual, or that would look out of place in the middle of a Rails application.

As a quick and simple solution, though, a global variable isn't out of the question: it has strong limitations, like it won't be shared across multiple server processes, and it'll go away any time the process restarts... but if those add up to a risk that you'll get, say, 4-6 notifications in an error-heavy 30 minute period -- maybe that's good enough? (It'd also give you a "reset on deploy" feature for free, so you know immediately if the problem's still occurring after you think you've fixed it.)

Comment: thanks, @matthewd!  I like your point about 'reset on deploy' :) Looking around more, I'm wondering if I can get away with just using a class variable. I'm running only one web dyno on Heroku, which I believe runs a single process inside the application virtual machine, so I *think* this means my variable will persist and be properly updated/shared as multiple users use the application...